# Change the color of text in a particular dxStatusBar1.Panel

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe7

How can you change the text color of a particular dxStatusBar1.Panel ? dxStatusBar is VCL  component of Devexpress.

Comment: Refer to: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q97946

Comment: That was 7 years ago !?

Comment: Yes, that should make it even more relevant, that's 7 more years of additions to this type of capability. Also why I didn't just put it as an answer. And for the record, I've never used DevExpress.

Comment: The only time  it matters how long ago something was written is when you try it and it no longer works. Did you try the information in the link @Jerry provided?

Comment: Yes, but it makes no difference. Using skin controller just changes the skin. Text remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panels have an OnDrawPanel event. Probably the easiest way is to hook into that event and then paint the panel as you would like it painted. Something like this:

```
procedure TFormTest.dxStatusBar1Panels1DrawPanel(Sender: TdxStatusBarPanel;
    ACanvas: TcxCanvas; const ARect: TRect; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.PanelStyle.Painter.FillBackground(dxStatusBar1, Sender, ACanvas, ARect);
  ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
  ACanvas.DrawText(Sender.Text, ARect, cxSingleLine or cxAlignVCenter or cxAlignLeft);
  ADone := True;
end;
```

You should add some checks to make sure that the painter is actually assigned and in the case where it's not assigned you would need to paint the background yourself.

Below is an example of the output.

[image: Colored Panel Picture]

Comment: I think this way you change it for the entire statusbar. Same thing as using skins.

Comment: @user3927897 This is the OnDrawPanel event for a specific panel, not for the whole status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way :

> dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].PanelStyle.Font.Color :=clRed;